# Variable not passing over to method paint

Tags: java, swing, graphics, mouselistener

I have been searching google for the past day and a half trying to figure this out.
As you can see I am trying to make the mouseClicked update the variables clickcolumnindex and clickrowindex in order to make the replaint() method in the mouseClicked method update and thus show the counter created by paint display within another column/row.

I feel this may be a really simple fix after my trying loads of things, I have kinda lost my path of thought.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

            class GridPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
            {
                int numCols;
                int numRows;
                int w;
                int h;
                int x;
                int y;
                int clickcolumnindex;
                int clickrowindex;


                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
                {
                    System.out.println("Mouse released.");
                }
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
                {
                    System.out.println("Mouse Pressed");
                }
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
                {
                    int clickcolumnindex = 7 * x / getWidth();
                    int clickrowindex = 5 * y / getHeight();
                    int x = event.getX();
                    int y = event.getY();
                    System.out.println("x position of click is: " +x);
                    System.out.println("y position of click is: " +y);
                    System.out.println("Click is in column " +clickcolumnindex);
                    System.out.println("Click is in row " +clickrowindex);
                    repaint();

                }


   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
      System.out.println("Mouse released.");
   }

   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
      System.out.println("Mouse Pressed");
   }

   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
      int x = event.getX();
      int y = event.getY();
      System.out.println("x position of click is: " + x);
      System.out.println("y position of click is: " + y);
      System.out.println("Click is in column " + clickcolumnindex);
      System.out.println("Click is in row " + clickrowindex);
      repaint();
   }

   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
      System.out.println("Mouse entered.");
   }

   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
      System.out.println("Mouse exited.");
   }

   public GridPanel(int nc, int nr) {
      numCols = nc;
      numRows = nr;
      addMouseListener(this);
   }

   Rectangle getRect(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
      // if input is out of range, return "null"
      if (thisCol < 0 || thisRow < 0)
         return null;
      if (thisCol >= numCols || thisRow >= numRows)
         return null;
      // otherwise, make and return the Rectangle
      int w = getWidth() / numCols;
      int h = getHeight() / numRows;
      int x = thisCol * w;
      int y = thisRow * h;
      Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
      return myRect;
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(Color.gray);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      // we'll use Graphics2D for it's "draw" method -
      // neater than the Graphics "drawRect" suppled
      // (which you could also use)
      for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
            Rectangle r = getRect(i, j);
            g2.draw(r);
         }
      }
      g2.setColor(Color.blue);
      Rectangle r1 = getRect(clickcolumnindex, clickrowindex);
      g2.fillOval(r1.x, r1.y, r1.width, r1.height);
      System.out.println("variable updates " + clickcolumnindex + clickrowindex);
   }

   // copied from the W2MouseEvents for convenience
   // (so we can run the program from GridPanel class too!)
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      W2MouseEvents w = new W2MouseEvents();
      w.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

W2MouseEvents.java:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class W2MouseEvents extends JFrame {
   GridPanel myGridPanel;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      W2MouseEvents w = new W2MouseEvents();
      w.setVisible(true);
   }

   public W2MouseEvents() {
      setTitle("Workshop 2 (Mouse Events): starting code");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setSize(500, 400);
      setLocation(300, 300);
      myGridPanel = new GridPanel(7, 5);
      add(myGridPanel);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two issues:
Variables do not magically auto-update themselves.
If `x` is changed, no variable which has got `x` on its righthand side (assuming they are in the same scope) get updated.
To clarify:

```
int x = 4;
int var = x + 1; // var == 5
x = 5 // var still is 5, not 6
```

Assuming you want to change `x` and `y` "globally" (as in "attributes of an instance of your class"), the second issue you'll have to address is

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
{
    int x = event.getX();
    int y = event.getY();
    // ...
}
```

What happens here is that you declare two *new local* variables `x` and `y` but whatever value you assign to them, your "global" variables `x` and `y` will not change
unless you leave out the declarative `int`.
This is not an issue if you *recalculate* the value of `clickColumnIndex` and `clickRowIndex` inside one of the mouseClicked/mousePressed/... methods.

**Edit**
I see you've moved the calculation of `clickColumnIndex` and its brother to the `mouseClicked` method. But as stated above, you are creating two *new* variables which *hide* the "global" ones. Simply remove the `int`.

Comment: I am trying what you have suggested but still not getting anywhere. here is the code I get from my println's of the variables that should be updated in paint.                                  variable updates 00
variable updates 00
Mouse entered.
Mouse Pressed
Mouse released.
x position of click is: 136
y position of click is: 88
Click is in column 0
Click is in row 0
variable updates 00
Mouse Pressed
Mouse released.
x position of click is: 136
y position of click is: 88
Click is in column 0
Click is in row 0
variable updates 00
Mouse Pressed
Mouse released.

Comment: I removed the int since you said but I receive a compile error :(

Comment: where did you remove it? If you declare e.g. `x` to be an `int` (`int x;`) as an attribute of your class, you can access that `x` in any method of that class. If you declare a *new* `x` inside of a method, you cannot access the global one anymore (not entirely true, but doesn't matter here).

Comment: All working now. Thank you for you're help. I now feel very stupid but marginally content now my program works :)

Comment: @Lewis: again please follow my recommendation to draw in `paintComponent(...)` not `paint(...)` this will get *very* important if you do animations ever (and you will). Dont' forget to call the super's paintComponent method too.

Comment: Thanks I will read up on PaintComponent() as a lot of my searches prior to this post brought it up. 1 Final question. My oval is only moving on the grid when I double click rather than one click. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: I don't want to sound unfriendly but would you be so kind as to accept one of the answers? (Stackoverflow works like this: Ask a question, wait for answers, if there are answers which help you, upvote them, if there is an answer which solves your problem / you like best - accept it)

Comment: No problem. Like I mentioned - First time I have posted. Just done so.

Comment: @tedil any help with the above. The mouse clicked only works as it should when it is clicked onto the pane twice.

Answer (score 1):

You set clickcolumnindex when you declare it, before a mouse event ever occurs. You need instead to set it in the mouse listener.

In other words, this is meaningless:

```
        class GridPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
        {
            int numCols;
            int numRows;
            int w;
            int h;
            int x;
            int y;
            int clickcolumnindex = 7 * x / getWidth();
            int clickrowindex = 5 * y / getHeight();
```

because at this point x is 0 and so is getWidth() (surprised you don't get a divide by zero error here).

You want to set clickXXXindex in the MouseListener's `mousePressed(...)` method instead. I prefer using `mousePressed(...)` rather than `mouseClicked(...)` as the former isn't as picky about if you move the mouse after pressing it.

Also, you'll want to do your drawing in the JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method, not its `paint(...)` method.

Comment: H.F.O.E -- It has been at the top of the page (which includes the calculation) ?

Comment: @Lewis: the calculation is meaningless at that location. It does this calculation only once when the class's object is created and never again. You need to do the calculation when the mouse is clicked.

Comment: I have now done this but the variables are still zero inside the paint method. (thank you for your help!)

Comment: @Lewis: here's the drill: if you make changes and still have problems, then post your latest code in the edit to your original post, but don't delete the original post but rather show the new code or changes as an addition to your post so as not to make the question too confusing to others.

Comment: cheers, buddy. Never posted on here so was just trying to find the edit button! :)

Answer (score 1):

The statements:

```
   int clickcolumnindex = 7 * x / getWidth();
   int clickrowindex = 5 * y / getHeight();
```

are not allowed outside constructors, methods or static initializer blocks.

As indicated by the HoverMeister, these are only assiged once. Why not have a separate method for updating these variables and a subsequent repaint()?